# why does a ruby method have itself as method

Tags: ruby

```
def moo
   puts "moo"
end

moo.moo.moo.moo
```

this gives

```
moo
moo
moo
moo
```

just an oddity, I was curious if this was done on purpose and served some purpose...

Comment: I just tried this in IRB and I'm not getting the same result.  How are you writing this script and how are you executing it?

Comment: which version of ruby? and do you have anything else that is overriding object?  Since if I try it on 1.9.2-p180 I get `NoMethodError: private method 'moo' called for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @Mario In IRB, Ruby 1.8.7  - Not sure if there is a special way to execute it ;)

Comment: +1 because this calls attention to top-level methods not being private in irb 1.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you're doing that in console, so you're actually defining the method on the `Object`, which then defines the method on all the children of `Object`... which is everything.  So your method:

```
def moo
  puts "moo"
end
```

Returns `nil`, and because you defined the method on `Object`, `NilClass` has the method as well, so you can call `moo` on `NilClass`.

If you do:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    1 + 1
  end
end
```

And then:

```
f = Foo.new
f.bar.bar
```

You get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for 2:Fixnum
```

Comment: awesome answer, thank you! Is this specific to my version then, or still consistent behavior in the 1.9 IRB ?

Comment: It changes in `1.9`.  `irb` in `1.9` actually defines the method as a private instance method on `main`, which is the object that `irb` runs as.

Comment: Also, your method in `irb 1.9` also will return an instance of `String`, which doesn't have the `moo` method defined on it, so you'll get the `NoMethodError`.

Comment: puts returns nil, and NilClass has the method 'moo', but it's private. See @Sepp2k 's comments on noodl's answer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're defining something on the `Object` class.  Because everything in Ruby is an `Object` and every method returns something (defaulting to `nil`), you can call that method on its own result.  The `moo` method returns `nil`, and  so what you are doing is calling `moo` first on the global object, and then on each `nil` returned.

You can more explicitly do this:

```
class Object
  def moo
    puts 'moo'
  end
end
```

If you generally want to chain methods, you could try this:

```
class Mooer
  def moo
    puts 'moo'
    self
  end
end

a = Mooer.new
a.moo.moo.moo.moo.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

`puts "moo"` returns `nil`. A method from a scope can be used in any scope below. As `moo` is in top scope, all objects can call it:

```
"teste".moo # => prints "moo"
```

If you don't want that, make `moo` private:

```
private :moo
moo # => ok
nil.moo # => NoMethodError
moo.moo # => prints once and raise NoMethodError
```

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't work.

You're defining moo as a method on the 'main' object. Calling moo should then work, but your method returns nil (because puts returns nil). You didn't define NilClass#moo, so moo.moo should fail, and does for me.

Comment: It's interesting. I get a 'private method `moo' called for nil:NilClass'
 error, not a 'undefined method 'moo' for nil:NilClass' as I expected.

Comment: @steenslag yeah, me too. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: He's not defining moo as a method on the main object (that would be `def self.foo`), he's defining it as a private instance method on Object. Either way `moo.moo` still shouldn't work. However in ruby 1.8's irb there was an inconsistency which made "globally" defined methods public instead of private (in irb, but not in normal ruby), which explains why the OP would see the behavior he sees.

Comment: @sepp2k - oh, ok. I'm not sure I see the difference between `def moo` and `def self.moo` in this case, since `self` is `main` and not `Object` but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @noodl: You're right that in most situations where `self` is not a class (i.e. inside a method or `instance_eval` block) `def foo` and `def self.foo`) do the same thing. However defining a method in the top-level is a special case. If `def foo` would define `foo` as a method on `main` it would not be callable from anywhere where `self` is not `main`, which would not be very useful. For that reason `def foo` will instead define a private instance method on `Object`, which then can be called from anywhere.

Comment: @sepp2k - I see. Thanks, that makes much more sense now :D